# Creating a submenu in React js using an array of elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Is there any way to create the following structure without dividing the array into two and mapping over it

```
arrayList=[Jeans, Jackets, Pants, Fragrance, Sunglasses, Health Products]
<div className='Flexbox'>
//arrayList1.map](//arrayList1.map)(x=>return(<li>x</li>))

<div className='first sublist'>

    <li>Jean</li>

    <li>Jackets</li>

    <li>Pants</li>

</div>

<div className='first sublist'>

//arrayList2.map](//arrayList2.map)(x=>return(<li>x</li>))

    <li>Fragrance</li>

    <li>Sunglasses</li>

    <li>Health</li>

</div>
```

Comment: Why you don't want dividing the array and mapping over it?

Comment: just wanted to know if there is any way to solve this using just one loop. Is using too loops efficient?

Comment: How do you define loop? If the array should always be split to two part, and you know how to split, you can use slice to split the array to two part and map each other, And spliting may be not a loop?

Answer (score 1):

Try to split first two half using `Array#reduce`. Then apply the map for parent then apply map for `li`

```
const arrayList = ['Jeans', 'Jackets', 'Pants', 'Fragrance', 'Sunglasses', 'Health Products'];

let res = arrayList.reduce((acc,curr,ind)=>{
  if(ind%3 == 0){ // splitting into two array
   acc[ind/3] = [];
  }
  acc[acc.length-1].push(curr) // push the value to last created array
  return acc
},[]).map((item)=>(
   <div className="first sublist"> //div wrap
      {item.map(text=>( //for inner text
        <li>text</li>
      ))}
   </div>
))
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, are you asking for something like this?

```
{ arrayList.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        (index <= arrayList.length / 2) ?
            <li> {item} </li>
            :
            null
    );
}}
```